# CS-Cart Hook "session_set_name_before" not working

Tags: php, session, hook, cs-cart

I tried to use the hook `session_set_name_before` in my CS-Cart custom payment module but it's not working anymore. So, could anyone provide a feedback/suggestion to resolve?

Note: I have followed the instructions provided in this link https://docs.cs-cart.com/latest/developer_guide/addons/hooking/php_hooks.html

System name:
CS-Cart version 4.11.5

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to achieve using the hook? What does your code look like?